# SQL, scope of column in subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to understand, what is the the scope of specific column in SQL when using subqueries in different places. For example

```
select (case(val) 
            when 1 then 'one' 
            when 2 then 'two' 
            else 'something else' 
        end) as description, val 
from (select 1 as val from dual);
```

With this query the val is available in select statement, and result is

```
Description | Val
-------------------
    one     |   1
```

But with the following query

```
select (case(val) 
           when 1 then 'one' 
           when 2 then 'two' 
           else 'something else' 
        end) as description, 
        (select 1 from dual) as val 
from dual;
```

Following error is raised (in Oracle)

```
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 263 Column: 14
```

Why the val isn't available in the latter example, what is the technical reason behind this?

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Of course you get an error in this query:

```
select (case val when 1 then 'one' when 2 then 'two' else 'something else' end) as description,
       (select 1 from dual) as val
from dual;
```

Where is `val` in the first expression coming from?  Certainly not from `dual`.

In general, you cannot refer to a column alias in the same `select` where it is defined (nor in `where` or `group by` either).

I find this unusual, because you are defining `val` *after* referring to it.  In my opinion, this should make it even more obvious that `val` is not defined.  But, the ordering doesn't matter.  You can't refer to `val` regardless of where it is defined.

You seem to understand the fix, which is to use a subquery or CTE to define the value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your second query `val` is no more a column name or alias rather a table alias name as seen in below code line. Then how do you expect that to be used in `CASE` expression?

```
(select 1 from dual) as val
```